# Updating iOS app that is removed the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to update an app that is removed from the app store. I mean I want to remove it, but I still want to deliver updates to my current users. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of updates you want to deliver. 
It won't be possible to deliver updated versions of your app

But you will still be able to deliver content updates for your app which is fetched from your own server, if you support such functionality in your app. As long as users have your app installed they will be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think thats possible. I would guess that they do nothing else then comparing the version number of the latest release in the appstore with the one installed. So if there is no app in the store they would have nothing to compare to, so no 'update'.